# None of my canon printers work with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: printing, canon

I have in my office many canon printers such as :

- IR 2016
- IR 2018
- IR 2420
- MF4300
- MF4410
- MF 4330
- LBP 6000

**NOTE**
Ubuntu by default installed all the HP printer drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the wiki regarding [printers in Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters). If you follow [Canon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon) you will see it has a specific [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon) you can use to install a lot of Canon printer models.

But still I myself would suggest to anyone asking me to opt for a HP. HP has a very good track record with Linux.

---

- More information about how to use a PPA here: [Personal Package Archives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).